# Passing awk variable to strftime

Tags: bash, csv, awk, gawk

I have a CSV in which the 2nd and 3rd columns are the date and time (in UTC) respectively.

```
Id,Date,Hour,Name,...
1,2016-02-01,13:52,name1,...
2,2016-02-01,11:02,name2,...
3,2016-01-30,17:43,name3,...
4,2016-01-29,20:07,name4,...
5,2016-01-29,20:05,name5,...
.
.
.
```

I need to convert and merge this to Germany time (generalized, CET/CEST). I concatenate first the 2nd and 3rd columns into an awk variable as `a`, but I have trouble passing this as second argument to function `strftime` :

```
TZ="Europe/Berlin" awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} NR!=1 {a=$2" "$3" UTC"} {print strftime("%F %H.%M.%S %Z", a)}' <csv-file>
```

How do I pass awk variable `a` within `strftime` function?

Comment: By putting `a` in the same scope as where you try to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, awk is powerful tool for text processing, however, for date and time, it is not so good.

If you want to use it's `strftime()`, you have to provide an awk accepted `timestamp`, e.g from awk's `systime() or mktime()`. However if you want to do the time zone conversion, the `mktime()` you cannot take. Because it will load the `datespec` in your local timezone.

Easier approach would be, using external gnu date command, there you could do pretty much control on the date.

I assume that handling columns with awk isn't problem to you, I just make an example with date part:

Assumen you have somehow made a string: `"2016-02-01 13:52 UTC"`

```
echo "2016-02-01 13:52 UTC"|awk -v q='"' 
       '{cmd="TZ=Europe/Berlin date -d"q$0 q" +"q"%F %H.%M.%S %Z"q;
        cmd|getline x;
        close(cmd);print x}'
```

This will give :

```
2016-02-01 14.52.00 CET
```

So timezone was converted. Note that the `close(cmd)` after the getline pipe is important.

Comment: If/when `cmd | getline` fails that will (possibly with no warning) output the previous value of `x`. You need something like `if ( (cmd | getline x) <= 0 ) x="N/A"`. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: Note that the `-d` option for `date` is for the GNU version in particular (coreutils). The `date` command in BSD, Solaris, etc functions differently. This seems to be a Linux-centric answer to an OS-unspecific question.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` date handling is not as flexible as you would think. You can't pass an arbitrary formatted timestamp to strftime.  I would revert back to system date
Here is one sample script:

```
$ echo 1,2016-02-01,13:52,name1,... | 
  awk -F, '{cmd = "date -d \"" $2 " " $3 "\" \"+%F %H.%M.%S %Z\""; cmd | getline d; print d}'

2016-02-01 13.52.00 EST
```

Comment: wait, is this result correct? `13:52 UTC` should be German time `14:52` right? it doesn't do the conversion, does it?

Comment: Can you explain to me the double quotes surrounding the variables $2 and $3?

Comment: they are actually outside of the double quotes, it's concatenating a date command string from strings and variables.  see it like this "xxx" ++  $2 ++ " " ++ $3 ++ "xxx".  However, I didn't incorporate the TZ, which might be your question.